# Considerable stutter/lag/pixelation in PDF file while zooming in

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, pdf, export, pixelation

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96798895/Untitled-2.pdf

I made this pdf in indesign, I don't know if it's an issue or not but when I zoom in to the file, say to any text or the logo, it stutters and then appears clearly. Why is this happening?
I traced the logo AtoS in illustrator which was an svg file, and then pasted that in indesign. Is it because of the file size or something related to compreesion?

I am attaching the indesign file https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96798895/welcome%40gatle.indd.

I have tried lowering the settings while exporting the file and it has reduced the problem but I want to know whether or not I am doing it right.

Comment: @go-me, I tried changing the options in the acrobat preferences and came up with this **page content and information: Use overprint preview: Always**. on changing the options to this value, the stuttering went away. Not sure how that will help though :\

Comment: If the answer below solved the problem, please tick the "accepted answer" tickmark. If it did not, and you solved it, please answer your own question and mark that as resolved. It will help the site and potentially other people with the same problem in the future.

Comment: I m just comenting that check if you do not have too many innecesary nodes on the traced logo.

Answer (score 1):

Your files look alright here, besides the bleed missing ;)

Maybe it's a hardware performance related issue. I couldn't reproduce the issue with or without the different rendering in the Acrobat preferences (smooth and all) but I suspect Acrobat is "working" on that rendering; try without the smooth line and all the rendering effect in Acrobat preferences in the "Page Display" panel.

Adobe Acrobat sometimes show vectors in a weird way but if you zoom in and it's sharp, it should be alright. And you used vectors, you cannot get a better quality! Your Indd file seems alright, I don't think the issue is there.

---

**Edit:**

If you checked "Use overprint preview: Always", it's actually good for you and you should have this option enabled!

If you get a bad overprint trapping on some of your text or image, you'll see it on your PDF and can fix it (or at least see it if you wanted it this way.)

[image: overprint and no overprint trapping]

---

**This is the kind of thing that can happen if you have overprint on some elements.**

By having that overprint preview enabled you'll know what's the issue if you wonder why some text seem to disappear or have weird colors. If it fixes you preview issue and maybe other potential trapping issues, that's a double win!

[image: Overprint issues]

[image: Overprint white trapping text disappear and invisible]

Comment: Hi, sorry for the extremely late reply. The problem that I was facing has just up and vanished somehow somewhere. It wasn't an overprint issue, just some hardware thingy. Thanks for your help anyways :D. Learned something new along the way! Thank you!